# how to refresh embedded page in vaadin (ExternalResource)?

Tags: vaadin

I am new to vaadin framework. I am trying to refresh the embedded page when I click on a button of a vaadin component.

I found that we can use Refresher add-on but I am quiet confused how to use it.

any suggestions ?

Comment: The refresher add-on is really used to setup multithreading. That is having for example a listener that continuously listens for a system trigger without locking the main thread.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by embedded page? Do you have a `BrowserFrame`?

Answer (score 4):

I also recommend you to use the refresher addon. I use it for my application as well and it's working perfect.

As a little example:

```
//Create the Refresher
final Refresher refresher = new Refresher();
//time period in ms when the Refresher shell call the attached listener
refresher.setRefreshInterval(5000); 
//listener that gets called every 5000ms in this example
refresher.addListener(new MyRefresherListener()); 
//add the Refresher component to your layout
myLayout.addComponent(refresher);
```

A implementation of the listener can look like the following:

```
import com.github.wolfie.refresher.Refresher;
import com.github.wolfie.refresher.Refresher.RefreshListener;

public class MyRefreshListener implements RefreshListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void refresh(final Refresher source) {
        System.out.println("I am getting refreshed");
        // add the refresh page of your application logic here
        // e.g. the same code you use for changing views when a button click is happening
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems adding the refresher to the layout

> > The method addComponent(Component) in the type AbstractOrderedLayout is not applicable for the arguments (Refresher)

Here's an example code of I used:

```
public class RefresherDemo extends UI  {
    Refresher refresher;
    Label timeLabel;    

    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);

        timeLabel = new Label(getTime());

        refresher = new Refresher();
        refresher.setRefreshInterval(500);
        refresher.addListener(new RefreshListener(){
            @Override
            public void refresh(Refresher source) {
                timeLabel.setValue(getTime());
            }
        });
        addExtension(refresher);        

        layout.addComponent(timeLabel);

    }

    public String getTime(){
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String d = dateFormat.format(date);
        return d;
    }

}
```